# No collision detected with 2D rigidbody

Tags: 2d, unity, physics

No collision detected with 2D rigidbody
0
I have a ZombieBoy with a circle collider2D and a box collider2D and a RigidBody2D . The player shots energy balls which has a Circle Collider2D and a Rigidbody2D. It is set to trigger. But i have also tried without it set to trigger.

The ZombieBoy has this on its script

```
        void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
       {
          Debug.Log ("Im hit! " + other.name);
       }

       void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
       {

          Debug.Log ("Im hit! " + collision.gameObject.name);
       }
```

But i get nothing in the console, and no breakpoints react.

Answer (score 1):

Should use:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
}
```